# Modify Nested JSON fields with Kafka Streams

Tags: json, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

Is it possible to apply filter on the Nested JSON fields with help of Kafka Streams? If Yes, how those fields can be addressed?

For example,

```
{
 "before":{
    "id":1,
    "name":"abc"  
  },
 "after":{
    "id":1,
    "name":"xyz"
}
```

and now if name is modified in after field I do not want to filter it but fields other than name are getting modified I want to filter that record.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The deserializer of the configured Stream Serde should return your object type. You can then filter just like a regular Java Stream

```
stream.filter(yourMesssage -> compareCDCRecords(yourMessage.getBefore(), yourMessage.getAfter()))
```

Comment: I think I had given half information. I have edited it can you try to answer it now?

Comment: My answer doesn't really change. You deserialize the data to an object, then apply a predicate on that object. Nested fields are accessed like any other field